# docker-compose up faile because python interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker-compose, pyenv

y OS is MacOS Ventura 13.6.3, and im running docker-compose up --build on my terminal, but im getting this error:

```
zsh: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11: no such file or directory
```

This is what i get when run `which python3`:

```
/Users/luicruz/.pyenv/shims/python3
```

`which python`:
/Users/luicruz/.pyenv/shims/python

`python3 --version`: Python 3.11.0

Someone nows how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like you're confusing the python installation on your local machine with the python installation that should be installed in the docker container (which would be defined in your Dockerfile).